# Prolog: how to portray_clause without new lines

Tags: prolog

portray_clause prints each atom on a new line. For example:

```
?- portray_clause((p(X):-q(X),r(X))).
p(A) :-
    q(A),
    r(A).
```

Is there a simple way to print the clause on a single line?

I have the following solution, but it is inelegant, and only works with SWI prolog, and not YAP.

```
with_output_to(atom(A), portray_clause((Head:-Body))),
split_string(A, "\n", '', Words),
atomic_list_concat(Words,'',Out),
writeln(Out).
```

Comment: you can use writeq(T) or format('~q.~n', [T])

Comment: The point of `portray_clause/1` is to pretty-print a clause. What do you need this for? If you have the clause, you can simply print it using any predicate for (formatted) writing, as suggested by @CapelliC.

Comment: My question was imprecise. I wanted to give the variables better names than _G3882, _G3883, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

```
numbervars(Clause,0,_),
format('~q.~n', [Clause]).
```